# Problem with Exploratory Factor Analysis for my 7 items measuring attitude on SPSS

Tags: spss, factor-analysis

My factor analysis using direct oblimin keeps giving me only partial results, stating 'Attempted to extract 2 factors. In iteration 25, the communality of a variable exceeded 1.0. Extraction was terminated.' 
Having inputted 7 items, two of which were reverse coded, which are together supposed to measure an attitude. However, my SPSS output shows the aforementioned statetement, only the initial communicatielies, and neither the factor nor the pattern matrix. Would anyone know what could be the solution?

Comment: This is what is sometimes referred to as a "Haywood case". Good places to start, in terms of guessing what's gone wrong, are: 1) you have too little data and/or 2) your indicators badly violate the assumptions of your estimator (guessing ML, and so multivariate normality).

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what extraction method you're using, though as @jsakaluk implies, it's commonly maximum likelihood estimation where Heywood cases, or negative estimated residual variances, occur. This can occur for various reasons, including not enough data, too few or too many factors specified, and a generally inappropriate model. In some cases the problem may not occur if a different extraction method is used.